# Command to power off (not reset) module in Cisco 6500?

Tags: cisco, cisco-6500

This switch has double supervisor engines.
I tried commands `no power enable module x` and `hw-module module x shutdown`
for test the second supervisor, but it doesn't work.

How can i test?

Comment: Are you trying to power off a supervisor? What are you actually trying to test? A `show redundancy` will show states, code versions, modes of operation, and other details. If you want to verify operation, a `redundancy force-switchover` will force the failover. There is no need to power off a supervisor to test the second one.

Comment: Ensure that you try the command `no power enable module x` under configuration mode.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using CatOS by any chance?
From [Cisco Catalyst-6500's power management page](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/22389-142.html#use)
Use of the CLI to Power Modules Up or Down
You can issue one of these commands in order to power down a properly working module from the command-line interface (CLI):

Catalyst OS (CatOS)— `set module power down module_number`

Cisco IOS® Software— `no power enable module slot`

Comment: i use the IOS and i don't have any chance using CatOS  thank you the comments :)